# Laravel Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my `users` table, I have this column:

`$table->string('email', 255)->unique();`

However, I am getting this error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
```

As per [this](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error) article, I wrote the following code in `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

However, the issue remains unsolved. Please help!

P.S. I am using Laravel 5.6.*

Comment: What's your MySQL / MariaDB version?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter It's `5.7.21` and the PHP version is `7.2.4`!

Comment: And the db collation? Is it `utf8mb4` in the config?

Comment: You may also try setting the database engine in the config: `'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Where's the config file?

Comment: It's in `config/database.php`.

Comment: That didn't help! I wrote the code just below `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`, btw! And while creating db, I didn't select any of the collation.

Comment: `$table->string('email', 249)->unique();` should work. `defaultStingLength` only works when you actually use the default string length instead of specifying your own

Comment: after you ad the line in `AppServiceProvider` class, run the following command in your terminal `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: I fixed it! The issue was with the Engine. I changed it to InnoDB. Thanks all of you.